# Preventing reset of VBA variables from excel recompile

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim TempVar As Integer

TempVar = NumNodes
NumNodes = NumNodes + 1
TempVar = NumNodes
Debug.Print "NumNodes + 1"

Call Node_Button_Duplication
Call Channel_Selection_Duplication

NumNodes = TempVar

Debug.Print "NumNodes = " & NumNodes 'Debug
Debug.Print "TempVar = " & NumNodes 'Debug
End Sub

Public Sub Channel_Selection_Duplication()

    Range("Q8:S8").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Range("Q8:S8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Channel Usage Selection"
    Range("Q8:S52").Select
    Range("Q52").Activate
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With
Range("Q8:S8").Select
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 36

End Sub

Public Sub Node_Button_Duplication()


Worksheets("Topology").Shapes("CommandButton1").Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Topology").Paste
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 339#
Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -12.75

End Sub
```

I'm trying to save the value of NumNodes (a global variable) before calling the 2 subroutines (Node_Button_Duplication and Channel_Selection_Duplication), the first subroutine called copies and pastes a command button in a spreadsheet. This, I believe, recompiles the VBA project and reset (all?) global variables.

I have tried to write to a cell and read back the value from the cell, but this did not work (essentially the same ideas as using a temp variable).

The above code, when run, causes both TempVar and NumNodes to be reset to 1 each run. I am wondering what the best way is to save the variable from being reset?

Comment: Are you using ActiveX buttons? Could you use the forms version instead?  Writing a value to a cell should also work, so if you had problems with that then post the code you tried.

Comment: I don't believe I'm using an ActiveX button. This is just a command button that is copied and pasted.

Comment: Hard to suggest fixes without knowing exactly what's happening in those subroutines.

Comment: Node_Button_Duplication is the subroutine which copies and pastes the command button.

Comment: I read that - can you include the code for that routine?

Comment: @Ehudz: That is not how I suggested using the temp sheet :)

Comment: Tested a bit more, and creating a new ActiveX definitely causes problem with global variables, so you should try the Forms button.

Comment: Gah! Why post again with almost the exact same issue that Siddharth is already helping you with ?

Comment: @TimWilliams: I am sorry. I saw this question too late. Else I would have suggested the same thing as you mentioned in your last comment. Ehudz, If you do post a separate question based on a previous question, it is always advisable to mention a link of the previous question. This ensures that the experts helping you do not waste their time :)

Comment: Oops, sorry guys. I thought it'd be clearer if I start a new question and easier for someone to search if they encounter the same problem. Will remember next time to link.

Comment: Perhaps whenever I give a cell the value of a variable, I am giving the cell a reference to the variable, instead of just the value, which may explain why writing the value to the cell, then reading back doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim NumNodes as Long

    NumNodes = Sheets("Temp").Range("A1").Value

    NumNodes = NumNodes + 1

    Sheets("Temp").Range("A1").Value = NumNodes

    MsgBox "NumNodes = " & NumNodes

    Call Node_Button_Duplication
    Call Channel_Selection_Duplication
End Sub
```

Ensure that you have a sheet Called "Temp"

Now try it.

Comment: This works, provided a value is written to "A1" of the Temp sheet beforehand. I wonder if there is a way to make this work without writing/reading to sheets and keeping it in the code?

Comment: `provided a value is written to "A1" of the Temp sheet beforehand` No that is not necessary :) It will work even if it is blank. The above code is tried and tested :)

Comment: sorry, the provided code does work assuming I'm starting my counter at 0. If I wanted to start at, say 1, I'd have to write that cell with 1 beforehand?

Comment: Yes you are right. You can do that or in the workbook open event set the value of that cell to 1.

Comment: ok, I am opting to use a sheet to hold global variable values and pre-populating them to save from recompile. Thanks!